# How can I use a string in an if-statement?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, if-statement, nsstring

I'm new to objective-c and I would like to know how to get the stringValue of an NSString and if it's equal  to photo then do `//something`

This is the code that I'm using, the NSLog prints "photo".

I'm developing for an iPhone.

```
NSString *getPageType = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                                 @"document.getElementById('pageType').name"];

    NSLog(@"%@", getPageType);



    if (getPageType == @"photo")
    {
        [UIButton animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
            downloadOverlay.alpha = 1;
            downloadOverlay.alpha = 0;
        }];

    }
```

Comment: you'd better append a `toString();` call to the end of your JavaScript else you won't get a string back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ([getPageType isEqualToString:@"photo"])
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
if ([getPageType isEqualToString:@"photo"])
```

Answer (score 2):

`getPageType == @"photo"` compares memory addresses (pointers).

`[getPageType isEqualToString:@"photo"]` does what you really want, i. e. comparing the contents of the two strings.

**`in C Language`**

```
const char *capital = "NewYork";

if(capital == "NewYork") // address compare

if (strcmp(capital,"NewYork")==0) // string compare
   printf("equal");
else
   printf("different");
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already got you answer, but I just wanted to point out you can also use `isEqual:` if you are feeling particularly slow.

If you use `isEqual:` you can pass more than just a string (e.g. `NSData`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` etc.) as it's argument.

It returns `YES` if the two objects are equal and `NO` if they are not. This is slower than using `isEqualToString:` when comparing just strings though.

Answer (score 0):

you Can Use Like

```
NSString *getPageType = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                                 @"document.getElementById('pageType').name"];

    NSLog(@"%@", getPageType);



        if ([getPageType isEqualToString:@"photo"])
    {
        [UIButton animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
            downloadOverlay.alpha = 1;
            downloadOverlay.alpha = 0;
        }];

    }
```